# Enforcing tag on spot fleet request

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, amazon-iam

i have a use case where i need to enforce the tag on spot fleet request. i am able to enforce tags on ec2 launch wizard but the same does not work on instances requested through spot fleet request.

This is my current policy to enforce tag on ec2 launch wizard. what shall be added to enforce the same for spot-fleet-request.

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/username": "${aws:username}",
                    "aws:RequestTag/REQUIRED_TAG": "true"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "REQUIRED_TAG",
                        "username"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/username": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Policy for spot fleet request

```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RequestSpotFleet",
                "ec2:ModifySpotFleetRequest",
                "ec2:CancelSpotFleetRequests",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotFleetRequests",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotFleetInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSpotFleetRequestHistory"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/username": "${aws:username}",
                    "aws:RequestTag/REQUIRED_TAG": "true"
                },
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "REQUIRED_TAG",
                        "username"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-ec2-spot-fleet-tagging-role"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html

Comment: Such instances don't have tags, so how you can enforce them?

Comment: we can add tag on instnces during the launch .
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/tag-your-spot-fleet-ec2-instances/

Comment: [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet-requests.html#tag-spot-fleet) they write: "When you tag a Spot Fleet request, the instances and volumes that are launched by the Spot Fleet are not automatically tagged. You need to explicitly tag the instances and volumes launched by the Spot Fleet. " Have you verified that  your instances get tagged as per your first link?

Comment: yes, instances do get tagged when tag is added during launch.

line from article explains the same `Amazon EC2 Spot Fleet now supports user tags that will automatically propagate to instances launched by your Fleets.`